# Как сократить этот код, и сделать его лучше?

Tags: python, telebot

Как сократить этот код

```py
@bot.message_handler()
def replay(message):
    if message.text in ['Стрижка ‍♀', 'Стрижка', 'cтрижка', 'Стрижку', 'стрижку'] or message.text in ['Мужская стрижка ‍♂', 'Мужская', 'Мужская стрижка', 'Женская стрижка ‍♀', 'Женская', 'Женская стрижка', 'Детская стрижка ', 'Детская', 'Детская стрижка']:
        button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        men_haircut = types.KeyboardButton(text='Мужская стрижка ‍♂')
        women_haircut = types.KeyboardButton(text='Женская стрижка ‍♀')
        kids_haircut = types.KeyboardButton(text='Детская стрижка ')
        button.add(men_haircut, women_haircut, kids_haircut)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выберите тип услуги', reply_markup=button)

        if message.text in ['Мужская стрижка ‍♂', 'Мужская', 'Мужская стрижка']:
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            men_haircut_hair_comparison = types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос')
            button.add(men_haircut_hair_comparison)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ‍♂', reply_markup=button)

        elif message.text in ['Женская стрижка ‍♀', 'Женская', 'Женская стрижка']:
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            women_haircut_hair_comparison = types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос')
            button.add(women_haircut_hair_comparison)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ‍♀', reply_markup=button)

        elif message.text in ['Детская стрижка ', 'Детская', 'Детская стрижка']:
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            kids_haircut_hair_comparison = types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос')
            button.add(kids_haircut_hair_comparison)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ', reply_markup=button)
```

Comment: Первое что пришло в голову - через словари. Сделать слова, по которым ищете, ключами, а значениями фукнции, куда перенести логику под ифами.

Comment: 'Стрижка ‍♀', 'Стрижка', 'cтрижка', 'Стрижку', 'стрижку' 'Мужская стрижка ‍♂', 'Мужская', 'Мужская стрижка', 'Женская стрижка ‍♀', 'Женская', 'Женская стрижка', 'Детская стрижка ', 'Детская', 'Детская стрижка' по сути можно можно заменить одним словом "стрижк"

Comment: `Выберите стрижку`


Исправлено на https://www.corrector.co/ru/

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать как то так.
Кнопки можно передавать распаковывая список.
И не надо проверять полное совпадение, достаточно ключевого слова

```
@bot.message_handler()
def replay(message):
    if 'стрижк' in message.text.lower():
        button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        buttons_label = ['Мужская стрижка ‍♂', 'Женская стрижка ‍♀', 'Детская стрижка ']
        button.add(*buttons_label)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выберите тип услуги', reply_markup=button)

        if 'мужская' in message.text.lower():
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            button.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос'))
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ‍♂', reply_markup=button)

        elif 'женская' in message.text.lower():
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            button.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос'))
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ‍♀', reply_markup=button)

        elif 'детская' in message.text.lower():
            button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            button.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Равнение волос'))
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выбирите стрижку ', reply_markup=button)
```

Comment: Можно еще сократить код минимум в 2 раза. В той части, где идет проверка на тип стрижки по сути разница только в смайлке, можно там формировать смайлик, а код добавления кнопки и отправки сообщения вытащить после проверок.